# Uncomputability of subset relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability

I suppose this obvious question should already be answered in plenty of places, but for some reasons I cannot find a proof of this anywhere.

Prove or disprove that their exist a set $X$ that is decidable, yet the relation $A\subseteq X$ is not decidable where $A$ is arbitrary decidable set.

And,

Prove or disprove that their exist a set $X$ that is decidable, yet the relation $X\subseteq A$ is not decidable where $A$ is arbitrary decidable set.

I am only beginner to computability, so I hope for some easy to understand proof if possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One route: How many decision procedures are there? How many sets?

A second: Have you heard of the halting set?

Comment: @James: yes, I have heard of them, but I'm not sure how that would help answering the question.

Comment: @James: Is "how many" useful here? Since we're only talking about _decidable_ sets, there are countably many of those, so no easy counting argument in sight.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Oh, goodness I misread the question! I shouldn't jump onto stack exchange just after waking up from a nap. Sorry about that Gina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First off**, if you have a solution to one of the halves, you also have one for the other -- just replace $X$ and $A$ with their complements, which preserves decidability and makes $A\subseteq X$ into $\overline X\subseteq \overline A$.

**Second**, there's an important subtlety here. The problem is about whether we can find some $X$ such that there is/isn't a machine $M$ that takes as input a decidable set $A$ and returns a boolean saying whether $A\subseteq X$ or not.

However, $M$ can't *literally* take $A$ as input, because most decidable sets are infinite, and the machine has to complete in finite time. Therefore, in order to make any sense of the problem we need to interpret it such that the input to $M$ is not $A$ *itself*, but the code/index for a machine/program that *decides* $A$. And that gives us lots of leverage because we know that there can be several *different* machines that decide the same $A$ but can't be *proved* to decide the same $A$.

Finally, a **hint:** Keeping the previous point in mind, you can actually take $X=\varnothing$ in the first half of the problem. In other words: It is impossible, given an always-halting machine, to decide whether the $A$ it decides is empty or not!

Comment: I do believe your final statement, but after a little thought I don't think it is as simple as a quick appeal to Rice's theorem. As the algorithm is only required to work on $e$ which happen to code characteristic functions the algorithm could (at least on one reading of the question) be allowed to fail to halt on inputs which do not code characteristic functions.

Comment: I got it! For any machine $M$ we associate with a it a machine that $M^{\prime}$, which is a machine that take in a number $n$, then simulate $M$ up to the $n$ step and accept if $M$ halt by that point. Then $M^{\prime}$ decide $\emptyset$ iff $M$ never halt. Hence decidability of whether the set decided by $M^{\prime}$ is a subset of $\emptyset$ is equivalent to halting problem! Thanks. PS. also I never heard of Rice's theorem; as mentioned, I'm still beginner.

Comment: @Gina: Yes, that was what I had in mind.

Comment: @James: true, Rice's theorem wouldn't be applicable here, for the reason you sketch.

Comment: The usual way for a Turing machine to take an infinite set as an input is to use the infinite set as an oracle. It's very common for machines to "literally" take infinite sets as inputs in this way. That is how I would interpret the original question, although it is not clear exactly what was intended. But, for questions like this, there will be parallel undecidability results if (a) we focus only on computable sets, represented by their indices, or if (b) we focus on arbitrary sets provided as oracles. (@Henning Makholm)

Comment: @Carl: True -- I suppose the oracle interpretation didn't even occur to me here because it's so obvious that you can't decide the subset relation with finitely many oracle queries.

Answer (score 3):

To see what's really going on, it's easier to begin by looking at arbitrary sets (in other words, temporarily ignore the requirement that the sets should be decidable/computable). So we just want a set $X$ such that there is no algorithm to tell whether an arbitrary set $A$ is a subset of $X$.  Because we are looking at arbitrary sets, we need to pass them to the algorithm as oracles.

Suppose that $\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ was finite. Then only a finite number of numbers are *not* in $X$. So we could just check that these numbers are not in $A$, and if not then $A$ would be a subset of $X$.  This can be done algorithmically. So we need $\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ to be infinite.

To take that option all the way, what if $X$ is finite? Say $X = \{1\}$ (we could pick any finite set). Now, to tell whether an arbitrary set $A$ is a subset of $X$, it looks like we need to check that every number other than $1$ is not in $A$. That's an infinite number of numbers to check, which seems impossible to do by algorithm.

To prove it's impossible, suppose otherwise (for a contradiction). Suppose $\phi_e$ is an algorithm such that, for an arbitrary set $A$, $\phi_e^A = 1$ if $A \subseteq \{1\}$ and $\phi_e^A = 0$ otherwise. Run the algorithm with input $A_1 = \{1\}$. The algorithm must halt in a finite number of steps and return $1$. Keep track of all the numbers which the algorithm asks about in $A_1$ - there can only be finitely many of these, because the algorithm halts in a finite number of steps. Let $N$ be the largest number that the algorithm queries when it is run on $A_1$. Then, if we let $A_2 = \{1, N+1\}$, the algorithm must return $1$ when run on $A_2$, since $A_1$ and $A_2$ agree on all the numbers that the algorithm will query. But $A_2 \not \subseteq X$, so the algorithm is not always correct, and we have our contradiction.

Now, that proof can be easily converted into a proof where we only look at computable sets and we pass them to the algorithm via their indices instead of passing them as oracles. This is simply because $X$, $A_1$, and $A_2$ are all computable!

In this way, a decent number of elementary questions about computability "on indices" can be answered by first solving the problem for arbitrary sets passed as oracles, and then checking that the sets that are actually used in the construction are computable.

---

Here is how to convert the proof to work with indices. It's actually a routine procedure, once you have the right viewpoint. Don't look at $A_2$ as fixed from the outset. Instead, imagine that the elements of $A_2$ are determined one at a time by an adversary. The adversary can defeat $\phi_e$ as follows. First, the adversary makes $A_2$ look more and more like $A_1$, but without committing that $A_2$ really will equal $A_1$ in the end. Eventually, $\phi_e$ has to give an answer, but since the adversary can always change $A_2$ at a later point, there is no answer $\phi_e$ can give that the adversary can't beat. (It's almost like the Saturday Night Live game "what number am I thinking of?".)

To work with indices, let $i_1$ be any index for a finite (or more generally, coinfinite) set $X$ and let $\phi_e$ be as above, but taking indices rather than oracles. We make an index $i_2$, using the recursion theorem, that will compute a set $B$. Given input $n$, $i_2$ first computes $\phi_e$ on input $i_2$ for $n$ steps.  If $\phi_e$ halts in $n$ or fewer steps and returns $1$, then $i_2$ puts $n$ in $B$ if and only if $n$ is not in $X$. Otherwise, $i_2$ puts $n$ in $B$ is and only if $n$ is in $X$. (Remember that $X$ is computable from index $i_1$, which we can code into $i_2$.) Now $i_2$ has played the same strategy with indices that $A_2$ played with oracles! Eventually, $\phi_e$ has to return some answer on input $i_2$. If $\phi_e $ ever returns $1$ (claiming $B \subseteq X$) then $i_2$ ensures $B \not\subseteq X$ because $B$ will be cofinite. Otherwise, if $\phi_e$ never returns $1$, then $i_2$ ensures $B \subseteq X$ (in fact $B = X$ in this case.) Either way, $\phi_e$ gets it wrong (or fails to return an answer, which is also a loss for $\phi_e$)

*Remarks*

1. The number $M$ in this second proof corresponding to $N$ in the proof above is the number of steps that $\phi_e$ takes to halt on input $i_2$. If $\phi_e(i_2) = 1$ then $B \supseteq \{M, M+1, M+2,\ldots, \}$.  The importance of $A_1$ and $A_2$ being computable is that we can make $i_2$ pretend to compute $A_1$ for some time, but at any moment we can switch it to computing a set like $A_2$.
2. The process of going from the proof with oracles to the proof with indices, using the recursion theorem,  is very general. Once you have the right perspective, the same technique can be applied to many elementary computability questions.  Essentially: whenever the strategy that the adversary uses to construct an oracle is computable, we can code that strategy into an index.
3. Another intuition to get from this sort of proof is that static analysis of indices is useless. There may be some trivial property that can be identified solely by looking at the index, but the more helpful intuition is that the only way to tell what an index does is to run it. Indeed, this is one reason to call them "indices" instead of "programs" - to emphasize that an index is a black box.

Comment: I'm not sure how this proof would look if you converted it to work with indices, as you promise? How would you define $N$? A machine that gets $A$ as an index is not limited to query it for particular inputs; it can do all sort of static analysis on the input machine and try to prove general theorems about it. And even if you get an $N$, you can't expect that the machine will react identically to $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: @Henning: I added an explanation. I wanted to write this out because it is rally a fundamental collection of techniques for working with computability.

Comment: I accept that the diagonalizing proof in the edit _works_ -- but it is not clear to me that it comes out of a systematic procedure applied to the oracle-based case. Indeed, I can't see that you ever use $A_1$ or $i_1$. You do say "let $i_1$ be any index for $A_1$", but neither $i_1$ nor $A_1$ appear anywhere in the rest of the proof ...

Comment: I had built $i_1$ into the construction itself to avoid being too general, but now I have edited it to make $i_1$ explicit. To see that this is a general technique, consider these problems: (1) it is not computable, given an oracle for a Cauchy sequence of rationals, to tell whether the sequence converges to $0$. (2) it is not computable, given an index for a Cauchy sequence of rationals, to tell whether the sequence converges to $0$. There is a direct strategy to prove (1), and since that strategy is computable, it can be adapted in exactly the same way as my answer to solve (2). @Henning

Comment: Similarly: (1) it is not computable, given an oracle for a group operation on $\mathbb{N}$, to tell whether the group determined by the operation is cyclic (2) it is not computable, given an index for a group operation on $\mathbb{N}$, to tell whether the group determined by the operation is cyclic. Again (2) follows immediately from the appropriate strategy to solve (1).

Comment: Just one more, which involves fewer prerequisites but is more trivial. (1) it is not computable, given an oracle for a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, to tell whether the set is finite (2) it is not computable, given an index for a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, to tell whether the set is finite

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see any generic process for adapting one proof to the other here. All I can see are two proofs for two situations. Each proof is valid, of course, but I don't see how you think they are similar in strategy, much less systematically derived from each other.

Comment: The systematic method is that there is a type of strategy to solve the oracle case: you pretend to construct an oracle for one object $\alpha$, which is computable, but as soon as the purported decision procedure says that you *are* constructing something with the appropriate property of $\alpha$, you switch to constructing an oracle for a different object $\beta$, also computable, whose oracle agrees with a sufficiently long initial segment of the oracle for $\alpha$. This method, which is very common, can almost always be adapted to work with indices exactly as above. @Henning

Comment: Hm, what I see here are two general theorems: Let $D$ be some subset of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ such that there exists $f\in D$ such that every _finite_ restriction of $f$ can extend to something outside $D$. Then (theorem 1) $D$ is not decidable when the input is an arbitrary function given as an oracle, and (theorem 2) $D$ is not decidable when the input is a total computable function given as a machine. Your examples all seem to fit as applications of these theorems. I don't think the proofs of theorems 1 and 2 feel very similar to me, apart from having the same premises.

Comment: Those theorems sound almost right, but for the index version you need a computable $f$ and the ability to compute, given a finite initial segment of $f$, an index for an extension of that segment that is not in $D$. That extra restriction holds in all the examples I listed. In my mind, the proof of the index version is just an "effectivization" of the proof of the oracle version, vaguely analogous to another common type of "effectivization": taking a boldface result in descriptive set theory and making it into a lightface result. @Henning

Comment: Hm, yes, right.

Comment: I have a rough idea of what is going on here, but I really don't understand whether this proof works, as the details escape me. In fact, I still find the assumption that the algorithm must check one-by-one to see whether an element is in the set is too strong an assumption: it makes the proof trivial; yet it does not seems to be true: replace "decidable set" with "regular language" and we end up with a wrong result. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @Carl "Given input $n, i_2$ first computes $\phi_e$ on input $i_2$ for $n$ steps." How does $i_2$ know its index if you are still constructing it?

Comment: @David Toth: that uses the recursion theorem, one of the most powerful of the basic theorems of recursion theory. It says, essentially, that in constructing a program we may assume we already know its index. For details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene's_recursion_theorem