# Is a set $\{ e \in \mathbb{N} | \#\{x \in \mathbb{N} | \phi_e(x) \downarrow \} = \#\mathbb{N}\}$ computable?

Tags: computability

Denote every partial computable function $f$ with its Godel number $e \in \mathbb{N}$ by $\phi_e$. Then let the halting set of $\phi_e$ be $W_e=\{x \in \mathbb{N} | \phi_e(x) \downarrow \}$ where $f(x)\downarrow$ means that $f$ halts on the input $x$. Define a set $E=\{ e \in \mathbb{N} | \#W_e = \#\mathbb{N}\}$.

Is $E$ computable?

Intuitively, $E$ is not computable since we would need to check that $\phi_e$ halts or does not halt on infinitely many inputs, but we require our proof to be finite. However, how could I prove it? Also, is there any way to convert the intuition directly into the proof that $E$ is not computable rather than constructing a tricky function and then derive a contradiction?

Comment: You can use the same method as in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873063/uncomputability-of-subset-relation/874662#874662 . Start by proving that there is no computable function $G$ that, given an oracle for an arbitrary function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, determines whether the range of $f$ is infinite.

Comment: For questions like this, there's a wonderful result called Rice's Theorem. It says that a set of the form $\{e:\text{something about }W_e\}$ is never recursive unless it's all of $\mathbb N$ or empty.

Comment: What does $\#$ mean? What does $\#W_e$ or $\#\mathbb{N}$ mean?

Comment: For a direct proof, suppose your set is computable. Then to know if $\Phi_e(e)$ halts, you can just create $e'$ so that $\Phi_{e'}(n) = \Phi_e(e)$ on every $n$. It follows that $e'$ is in your set iff $\Phi_e(e)$ halts. Therefore the halting problem would be computable, and we know it is not.

Comment: @user150396 $\#A$ denotes the cardinality of a set $A$.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your answers.